Variable of a space-containing path causing issues in WinSCP commandline
I'm trying to automate some WinSCP SFTP transfers in a PowerShell script, while still keeping a lot of the relevant data stored in variables.
$outFileName = Split-Path $outFile -Leaf
$outFilePath = Split-Path $outFile -Parent

& $winScpComPath `
    /log=$winScpLog /ini=nul `
    /command `
        "open $sftpUrl -hostkey=$sftpHostKey" `
        "lcd $outFilePath" `
        "cd $sftpTargetPath" `
        "put $outFileName" `
        "exit"

This works perfectly if the outFilePath is a path with no spaces (C:\Scripts) but fails if the path contains a space ("C:\Program Files"), presumably since it is now wrapped in double-quotes.
The error is

Too many parameters for command 'lcd'.

I suspect it's treating the additional double-quotes as two variables, splitting the path up.
Cursory research shows many others have problems with WinSCP scripting commands either not being surrounded in enough, or too many double-quotes, however, none I can find is trying to do it within a variable like this, and needs it to adapt to space-containing paths.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! I can also attach the WinSCP log file if needed, but it just shows the same error as what's in the console.
So far I've tried:
Escaping the spaces and quotes of the path like so:
$outFilePath -replace ' ', '` '
$outFilePath -replace '"', '`"'
# or this one
$outFilePath -replace ' ', '\ '
$outFilePath -replace '"', '\"'

None of these worked, and truth be told I can't tell if I should be using PowerShell's escape character or WinSCP/PuTTY's escape character.

You have to wrap the WinSCP command parameter with spaces into double double-quotes. And in PowerShell, those need to be further escaped with backticks.
All documented here:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#syntax
So this should do:
        "lcd `"`"$outFilePath`"`"" `

Also beware of PowerShell 7.3.0 breaking command invocation.

WinSCP GUI can even generate PowerShell script template for you, with all the quoting and escaping:  https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl

Though in general, for use from PowerShell, it's better to use WinSCP .NET assembly:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell

That did it! Thanks a ton! Sorry I can't yet upvote your answer, not enough rep.

good answer. that is perhaps the ugliest escape sequence I've ever seen.
